# From the book of Benjamin Grahm "The Inteligent Investor" : chapter 5, pg 115, what does he mean imposing some limit

Tags: investing, financial-literacy, stock-analysis

I am totally new to finance and investing world, hence please bear my basic question.

I have a query on Ben's book The intelligent investor Page #115.

> point #4 it says : The Investor should impose some limit on the price
>   he will pay for an issue in relation to its average earnings over past
>   7 years. we suggest that this limit be set at 25 times such average
>   earning, and not more than 20 times those of the last 12 months.

Does he mean that you should not pay more than $250, if we consider particular issue is having earning average of $250 for past 7 years.

Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It talks about [Price to Earnings ratio](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/price-earningsratio.asp). Generally if the average P:E over 7 years is < 25, it is undervalued and one should buy. If the P:E > 25; it is expensive.

The P:E may not be the only [and right] indicator; quite a few new generation companies have very high P:E as these are growth sectors. Quite a few heavy weight old companies that have lost relevance in today's world can have lower P:E's

Answer (score 5):

There is no dollar amount that he specifies in this point. The mathematical equation he gives could be formulated as: where the company earns $x per share over the last 12 months, don't pay more than $20*x for that share.